# не работает питон

Tags: python, apache2, freebsd

Вместо интерпритации питон скрипта вводится его содержимое как обычный текст, `python 3`, система `freebsd 11`, `apache 2.2`.

В чём может быть дело?

Теперь пишет Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /gis.py on this server.

после того как поправил конфиг апача

Comment: Оо... это уже интересно... есть такие к тебе вопросы: 1) какой фрейм ты используешь 2) какой протокол ты используешь http или https 3) uwsgi для апача поставил и работает без ошибок 4) что пишут логи апача 5) в нете есть много решений по этому поводу, но основной упор идёт на то, что фрейм работает исключительно на 127.0.0.1, а вот в мир смотрит сам апач. чтоб это сделать, нужно, для апача прописать конфиги, а сам фрейм запускать в демоне... так что прошу дать ещё такую информацию

Comment: приведите пример запуска скрипта

Comment: http использую, ничего не ставил, только питон 3.6. при этом апач+sql работают нормально, что в конфигах апача добавить нужно?

Comment: зря вы так. я вот столкнулся именно с этими проблема когда несколько лет назад подымал веб-сервера... и получал ошибки по каждому поводу и без повода... мне помогли очень старые маны по установке, а также пришлось читать логи, так как вылезла ошибка не совместимости версий апача... так что это ответ

Comment: для веб-серверов нужно ставить модуль wsgi, который позволит веб-серверу обрабатывать питоновский код. могу дать такую наводку (но это только наводка, но не решение), скачай исходники такого фрейма как web2py, там есть папочка скрипты, подсмотри там как попробовать сделать... но редупреждаю, тебе придётся конфижить апач, так как он у тебя очень старый. это уже у гугла спрашивай

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сделать файл исполняемым.

Так же попробуйте запустить из консоли. Может потребоваться дописать вначале `python3 file.py`

Возможен ещё один вариант, самой первой строкой указать полный путь к питону.

Answer (score -1):

По поводу апача тут вообще отдельная тема может быть. 
Как вариант дело может касаться: `apt-get install libapache2-mod-python` (в твоём случаи `apt-get install libapache2-mod-python3`)

Comment: у автора вопроса freedsd, там нет apt-get. pkg install есть

Comment: [Настройка для freebsd](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/apache22-mod_wsgi-python-3-2-help-me-configure-it.26081/)